# MYSQL Stored Procedures INSERT Fails

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, insert

I am using MYSQL version 5.5
I am trying to insert the following  procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE  `myTestProceed3ure` ( IN _id INT ) 
IF( SELECT COUNT( * ) FROM  `tbl_search_counter` WHERE user_id = u_userid ) >0
THEN 
(SELECT COUNT( * ) FROM  `tbl_search_counter` WHERE user_id = u_userid);       
ELSE
(INSERT INTO  `tbl_search_counter` (`user_id` ,`time_searched`) VALUES ('165',  '7'));       
END IF
```

But for whatever reason I get the following error message

> **1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'INSERT INTO `tbl_search_counter` (`user_id` ,`time_searched`)
>   VALUE' at line 6**

I really don't understand because when I do the following request I do not experience problem

```
CREATE PROCEDURE  `myTestProceed2ure` ( IN  `_id` INT ) 
INSERT INTO  `tbl_search_counter` (`user_id`, `time_searched`) VALUES ('15',  '7')
```

or the following

```
CREATE PROCEDURE  `myTestProceed3ure` ( IN _id INT ) 
IF( SELECT COUNT( * ) FROM  `tbl_search_counter` WHERE user_id = u_userid ) >0
THEN 
(SELECT COUNT( * ) FROM  `tbl_search_counter` WHERE user_id = u_userid);
ELSE 
(SELECT COUNT( * ) FROM  `tbl_search_counter` WHERE user_id = u_userid);
END IF
```

If someone has any idea what I am doing wrong, let me know...

Thanks

Comment: Look at the variable u are using in proc. Wrong

Comment: Please explain what you want the stored procedure to be doing.

Comment: I think you missted BEGAIN an END in stored procedure... So check syntax for that :)

Comment: I find out, I should not have put the brackets before the INSERT function, if I do this it works

Answer (score 0):

What is your stored procedure supposed to be doing?  You are not referencing the parameter to the stored procedure and `u_userid` seems undefined.

If you just want to insert an `id` that doesn't currently exist, then here is one way:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE  `myTestProceed3ure` (IN _id INT ) 
    INSERT INTO  tbl_search_counter(user_id, time_searched)
        VALUES (_id,  '7')
        ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE user_id = values(user_id)    
END IF;
```

Comment: at the moment I just wanted to make it work then I would change the code. Let me try your syntax and come back, thanks

Comment: it did not work, what I am trying to do is an increment. if the user exist we increment the time_searched. If the user does not exist we add him in the database.  link to the error message I got with your request http://postimg.org/image/715n1v34v/

Comment: I find out, I should not have put the brackets before the INSERT function, if I do this it works

Answer (score 0):

Final answer: I should not have put () before the INSERT...

```
CREATE PROCEDURE  `myTestProceed3ure` ( IN _id INT ) 
IF( SELECT COUNT( * ) FROM  `tbl_search_counter` WHERE user_id = u_userid ) >0
THEN 
(SELECT COUNT( * ) FROM  `tbl_search_counter` WHERE user_id = u_userid);       
ELSE
INSERT INTO  `tbl_search_counter` (`user_id` ,`time_searched`) VALUES ('165',  '7');       
END IF
```